# ExpandabeListView not support ChildClickListener in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using expandable listview to show states of india according to south,north,east,centeral.States list show like that ,but when apply onChildclickListener to expandableListView no response.I want when click state of india a new activity open.

1. **expandable listview**

   ```
    <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/indiaParts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:scrollbars="none"
   />
   ```
2. **list_group.xml**

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/group_header_bg"
   android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/tag_img"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
       android:src="@drawable/group_down"       
     />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/group_title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       android:text="Sample"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="18dip"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       />
   ```
3. **list_group_item.xml**

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/group_item_normal"
     android:id="@+id/groupItem"
     android:clickable="true"
     >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/item_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
           android:text="sample"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:layout_gravity="center" 
           android:gravity="center"
           />

     </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. **Adapter class**

   ```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

   private Context mContext;
   private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
   private ArrayList <GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
   private int[] groupStatus;

   public ExpandableListAdapter(Context pContext,
           ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
           ArrayList<GroupEntity> pGroupCollection) {
       mContext = pContext;
       mGroupCollection = pGroupCollection;
       mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
       groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];

       setListEvent();
   }

   private void setListEvent() {

       mExpandableListView
               .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
                   }
               });

       mExpandableListView
               .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
                   }
               });



   }

   @Override
   public String getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getStatesList().get(arg1).getStateName();
   }

   @Override
   public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3,
           ViewGroup arg4) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       ChildHolder childHolder;
       if (arg3 == null) {
           arg3 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                   R.layout.list_group_item, null);

           childHolder = new ChildHolder();

           childHolder.title = (TextView) arg3.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
           arg3.setTag(childHolder);
       }else {
           childHolder = (ChildHolder) arg3.getTag();
       }

       childHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getStatesList().get(arg1).getStateName());
       return arg3;
   }

   @Override
   public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getStatesList().size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return mGroupCollection.get(arg0);
   }

   @Override
   public int getGroupCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return mGroupCollection.size();
   }

   @Override
   public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return arg0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       GroupHolder groupHolder;
       if (arg2 == null) {
           arg2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group,
                   null);
           groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
           groupHolder.img = (ImageView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.tag_img);
           groupHolder.title = (TextView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
           arg2.setTag(groupHolder);
       } else {
           groupHolder = (GroupHolder) arg2.getTag();
       }
       if (groupStatus[arg0] == 0) {
           groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
       } else {
           groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
       }
       groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getGroupName());

       return arg2;
   }

   class GroupHolder {
       ImageView img;
       TextView title;
   }

   class ChildHolder {
       TextView title;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasStableIds() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.out.println("vcvv.........."+true);
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }
5. **Activity class**

   ```
          expandableListView=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.indiaParts);

       expandableListAdapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(StatesScreen.this, expandableListView, groupEntityList);
       expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);


       expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

           @Override
           public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                   int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Toast.makeText(StatesScreen.this, "Hi click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               System.out.println("clicked..............////."+groupPosition);
               Intent categoryList=new Intent(StatesScreen.this,CategoryList.class);
               startActivity(categoryList);
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: Is item highlighted then you try to push?

Comment: @neworld child items are not hihlighted.

Comment: @neworld this mehod only print value on scroll. public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("vcvv.........."+true);
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appear then your children's View has own focusable element. You can remove it by removing android:clickable from children layout or set to false:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/group_item_normal"
  android:id="@+id/groupItem"
  <!-- remove clickable from here -->
  <!-- or android:clickable="false" -->
  >
```

If you children element doesn't has any clickable and focusable elements, then work standart ListView focusable.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: & one thing,who says your english is bad.